# Electron gives blank Screen when try to serve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, react-router-dom

I have this problem regarding `electron`, I tried to upgrade my electron version from `7.0.0` to `18.2.3` but I got stumbled in this problem where the screen always give me a blank screen after I try to run it in my staging environment.

before someone want to mark it as duplicate, I want to clarify first that I tried the solution but still not work, this is some thread in here that I already tried but still no luck:

1. [electron-shows-blank-screen-when-running-in-development-yet-works-in-production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60388137/electron-shows-blank-screen-when-running-in-development-yet-works-in-production)
2. [electron-shows-white-screen-when-built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925634/electron-shows-white-screen-when-built)
3. [getting-blank-screen-in-windows-after-electron-builder-react-electron-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200402/getting-blank-screen-in-windows-after-electron-builder-react-electron-app)
4. [blank-screen-when-running-electron-package-app-how-to-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796181/blank-screen-when-running-electron-package-app-how-to-debug)
5. [electron-angular-6-blank-screen-on-production-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815416/electron-angular-6-blank-screen-on-production-application)

for information, I use `react` for my project, after try to read some thread I think I'm starting to figure probably the problem occur around the implement of `hashRouter` or the way of my directory, but regarding the directory, I think the way I use it already correct since it give a different color of blank screen such as like this:

**Blank screen when using wrong path**

```
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
```

**Result:**

[image: result with wrong path]

**Blank screen when using correct path**

```
  // mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app.html`);
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'app.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
```

**Result**

[image: result with the correct path]

I feel like I 1 step closer to solved it but quite confused as what problem happen when electron only return this blank screen.

this is my main.dev.ts looks like:

```
import path from 'path';
import { app, BrowserWindow, screen, ipcMain } from 'electron';
import { autoUpdater } from 'electron-updater';
import log from 'electron-log';
import MenuBuilder from './menu';

const url = require('url');
const { download } = require('electron-dl');
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` });

export default class AppUpdater {
  constructor() {
    log.transports.file.level = 'info';
    autoUpdater.logger = log;
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
  }
}

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null = null;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const sourceMapSupport = require('source-map-support');
  sourceMapSupport.install();
}

if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ||
  process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true'
) {
  require('electron-debug')();
}

const installExtensions = async () => {
  const installer = require('electron-devtools-installer');
  const forceDownload = !!process.env.UPGRADE_EXTENSIONS;
  const extensions = ['REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS', 'REDUX_DEVTOOLS'];

  return Promise.all(
    extensions.map(name => installer.default(installer[name], forceDownload))
  ).catch(console.log);
};

const createWindow = async () => {
  if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ||
    process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true'
  ) {
    await installExtensions();
  }

  const { width, height } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  let widthWindow = 1200;
  let heightWindow = 800;
  if (width <= 1280 || height <= 800) {
    widthWindow = width;
    heightWindow = height;
  }
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: widthWindow,
    height: heightWindow,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.E2E_BUILD === 'true'
        ? {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            zoomFactor: 1.0,
            devTools: true
          }
        : {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/renderer.prod.js'),
            zoomFactor: 1.0
          }
  });

  // mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app.html`);
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'app.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));

  mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    if (!mainWindow) {
      throw new Error('"mainWindow" is not defined');
    }
    if (process.env.START_MINIMIZED) {
      mainWindow.minimize();
    } else {
      // if (width <= 1280 || height <= 800) mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
      mainWindow.show();
      mainWindow.focus();
    }
  });

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  const menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(mainWindow);
  menuBuilder.buildMenu();

  ipcMain.on('download', (event, info, id) => {
    info.properties.onProgress = status =>
      mainWindow.webContents.send('download progress', status, id, info.url);
    download(mainWindow, info.url, {
      ...info.properties,
      saveAs: false
    }).then(dl => mainWindow.webContents.send('download complete', id));
  });

  // Remove this if your app does not use auto updates
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') new AppUpdater();
};

/**
 * Add event listeners...
 */

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // Respect the OSX convention of having the application in memory even
  // after all windows have been closed
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// Use app.removeAllListeners('ready'); if you set your windows personalize in Dark Theme
app.removeAllListeners('ready');

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
});

ipcMain.on('DEVICE_INFO_SCREEN', event => {
  const { width, height } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  event.returnValue = { width, height };
});
```

as for route, since I have a hunch that probably it has a problem regarding hashroute, currently I'm using `Routes` from `react-router-dom: 6.3.0` and it looks like this: (this is my `Routes.tsx`)

```
import { Routes as Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

<App>
  <Router basename={routesPath.SPLASH}>
    <Switch>
        <Route
            path={routesPath.LIVESTREAMREPORT}
            element={<LivestreamReport />}
        />
        <Route
            path={routesPath.LIVESTREAMHISTORY}
            element={<LivestreamHistory />}
        />
        
       // Start Section of Another path in my project
       ...
       // End Section of Another path in my project
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</App>
```

There is one time that I tried `HashRouter` and I change it like this, but it still not solved my problem, am I wrong in implement it, or it is another problem with another solution to solved this problem?

```
import { Routes as Switch, Route, HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

<App>
  <Router basename={routesPath.SPLASH}>
    <Switch>
        <Route
            path={routesPath.LIVESTREAMREPORT}
            element={<LivestreamReport />}
        />
        <Route
            path={routesPath.LIVESTREAMHISTORY}
            element={<LivestreamHistory />}
        />
        
       // Start Section of Another path in my project
       ...
       // End Section of Another path in my project
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</App>
```

Can someone help me to solve this? I'm quite confused since there is no error in my dev console

**EDIT 1**
After I tried to move back to the initial version and do the step once again, finally my apps show exactly a white screen error like everyone (the dark screen is not show anymore), I think I starting to get closer to solved this problem, but I tried a lot of way based on white screen thread, I still failed to solved it, to make easier,

Here is my `index.tsx` looks like:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer as ReactHotAppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import Root from './Screen/Root';
import { configureStore, history } from './store/configureStore';
import './app.global.css';

const store = configureStore();

const AppContainer = process.env.PLAIN_HMR ? Fragment : ReactHotAppContainer;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
  render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Root store={store} history={history} />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
);
```

and this is how I render my component in `Root.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ipcRenderer, shell } from 'electron';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/database';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
import { History } from 'history';
import { Store } from '../reducers/types';
import Routes from '../Routes'; // --> you can see this file above

// this is my render function

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.props.store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={this.props.history}>
          <div style={{ height: '100%', overflow: 'auto' }}>
            <Routes />
          </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

currently this is what I got:
[image: There is no error in my devtools and only return blank screen]

Am I implement something wrong in here?